# How to Check for Application Inactivity in .NET 2010

Tags: vb.net-2010

How to Check for Application Inactivity in .NET 2010...

I did not try anything yet since I don't know how to start...

Need to check and set to auto logout the Application once it reach the time alloted for inactivity....